# Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream for CreateFile in isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

I am trying to create a file in the Isolated storage using following code,

```
IsolatedStorageFile storageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
storageFile.CreateFile("Html\\index.html");
```

but I am getting exception while doing the same.. which says.

> > System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException: Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream

There are no operation performed apart from this operation.

Comment: Have you created the `Html` folder first? Also, are you sure the `index.html` file doesn't already exist?

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to create the `Html` directory first.  As [IsolatedStorageFile.CreateDirectory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.createdirectory.aspx) will succeed if the directory already exists, you can just do

```
IsolatedStorageFile storageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
storageFile.CreateDirectory("Html");
storageFile.CreateFile("Html\\index.html");
```

Comment: I am doing a "isf.FileExists()" check before creating the file, but I am still facing the problem.

I also created the Html folder before creating the file. 
STill getting the same exception
--
An exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
----

Comment: Is there anything in the InnerException of the IsolatedStorageException?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was the directory path.

This code worked to write to a file.

```
IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    string folderfilename = folder.Path + "\\" + fileName;
    try
    {
        StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(folderfilename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, myIsolatedStorage));
        writeFile.WriteAsync(content);
        writeFile.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
```